# Visual Studio 2010: Metadata file ".../Debug/Graph.dll" could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I took a solution developed in visual studio 2005 and attempted to build the solution in visual studio 2010 express. The files not being found are .dll files. The project is written in C#. I've seen a couple people with similar problems online, however I have yet to find any useful responses. I had the suspicion it may have to do with the .Net framework, but I check the version on the new and old machine and found them to be the same. Anything that could point me in the right direction would be great, thanks.

Comment: Does the Express version of VS2010 support building libraries (.dll)?

Comment: First, have you checked that the files are there? If they are not, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I am using VS 2013:

- Clean every project individually (right-click > Clean)
- Build every
  project individually (right-click > Build)
- Build the startup project
  (solution)

For some reason, cleaning the solution had a different effect than cleaning every project individually.